# regex pattern for all possible float combo's with 2 digits

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a solution to create my pattern in order to match only the following situations:
1% ; 32% ; 01% ; 12,2% ; 12,22% ; 13.2% ; 13.24% ; 1,4% ; 1.5% ; 1,44% ; 4.33%

```
pattern = '^((\d{1,2}[,.]\d{1,2})|([0-9]{1-2}))%\Z'
```

I am pretty close, however my OR expression is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just placed an optional pattern on the decimal part. You can use the following:

```
r'(\d{1,2}(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?)%'
```

Using `re.findall` you can get all the numbers:

```
import re
floats = '1% ; 32% ; 01% ; 12,2% ; 12,22% ; 12.2%'
re.findall(r'(\d{1,2}(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?)%', floats)
```

`re.findall` returns:

```
['1', '32', '01', '12,2', '12,22', '12.2']
```

Answer (score 0):

this will be more accurate

```
^(\d{1,2}[\.\,])?\d{1,2}%$
```

this data will not match:

4.3321231231%
.3321231231%
21231231%

but `r'(\d{1,2}(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?)%'` above will match